# Unable to create record via nested attributes Rails API

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently trying to create an Order instance. There is an association of the model `Order` with `Items`. The association is as follows. `Order` has many `Items`. I try following the documentation https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  ##
  private

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:description,
                                  items_attributes: [:id, :quantity])
  end
end
```

From the following post, it shows that the id has to be pass in the params. [Rails 5 Api create new object from json with nested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343652/rails-5-api-create-new-object-from-json-with-nested-resource)

```
params = {order: {description: "this is a test"}, items_attributes: [{id: 3, quantity: 3, description: 'within order -> item'}]}
=> {:order=>{:description=>"this is a test"}, :items_attributes=>[{:id=>3, :quantity=>3, :description=>"within order -> item"}]}
[7] pry(main)> order_test = Order.create!(params[:order])
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  Order Create (62.9ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("description", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["description", "this is a test"], ["created_at", "2019-05-30 23:31:39.409528"], ["updated_at", "2019-05-30 23:31:39.409528"]]
   (4.6ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Order:0x00007ff91556e4b8 id: 14, description: "this is a test", created_at: Thu, 30 May 2019 23:31:39 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Thu, 30 May 2019 23:31:39 UTC +00:00>
```

I create an order however when I check for the `items` it returns an empty array.

```
=> #<Order:0x00007ff9142da590 id: 14, description: "this is a test", created_at: Thu, 30 May 2019 23:31:39 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Thu, 30 May 2019 23:31:39 UTC +00:00>
[11] pry(main)> Order.last.items
  Order Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY "orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 14]]
=> []
```

Here is the table for items:

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.references :order, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :quantity
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in the order the parameters were being passed.

```
{:order=>{:id=>22, :description=>"this is a test", :items_attributes=>[{:order_id=>22, :quantity=>3, :description=>"within order -> item"}]}}
```

This solved it:

```
order = Order.create!(params[:order])

<Order:0x00007ff918039ee0 id: 22, description: "this is a test", created_at: Fri, 31 May 2019 01:39:23 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Fri, 31 May 2019 01:39:23 UTC +00:00>
[39] pry(main)> order.items
  Item Load (114.8ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 22]]
=> [#<Item:0x00007ff9180394b8
  id: 4,
  order_id: 22,
  quantity: 3,
  description: "within order -> item",
  created_at: Fri, 31 May 2019 01:39:23 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 31 May 2019 01:39:23 UTC +00:00>]
```